# How to animate the one image button to the top of four or five buttons?

Tags: ios, animation, button, imagebutton

I am new to animation in iOS development. How to animate the one image button to the top of four or five buttons in iOS? Whenever I tap any of the buttons, the image button has to be placed at the top of that button.

Answer (score 0):

Bring the button to front by giving

```
[self.view bringSubViewToFront:buttonName];
```

and implement animation like this

```
CGRect basketBottomFrame = basketBottom.frame;
basketBottomFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

basketTop.frame = basketTopFrame;
basketBottom.frame = basketBottomFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

In .h file,declare the imageButton as:

```
    int selectedCurveIndex;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *mvngButton;
   -(IBAction) btnMoveTo:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) btnDownUnder:(id)sender;
```

In .m file,

```
static int curveValues [] = {
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut,
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn,
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut,
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear};

   -(IBAction) btnMoveTo:(id)sender
{
UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
[mvngButton moveTo: CGPointMake(btn.center.x - (mvngButton.frame.size.width/2),btn.frame.origin.y - (mvngButton.frame.size.height + 5.0))duration:2.0 option:curveValues[selectedCurveIndex]];
}
-(IBAction) btnDownUnder:(id)sender
{
UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
[btn downUnder:1.0 option:curveValues[selectedCurveIndex]];
}
```

For the remaining four buttons,in xib file,`touchupinside` with the    `-(IBAction) btnMoveTo:(id)sender` method.
And for the imageButton in xib file,`touch up inside` method with the `-(IBAction) btnDownUnder:(id)sender` method and the `referencing outlet` with the `mvngButton`.